# How to copy current url of website in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I was looking for a way to copy the text from url so that Users can share the link with others.

Comment: Wouldn't users just highlight the address and copy/paste it to wherever?

Comment: yes , but it's an extra feature to have, for example if someone want's to share some product with someone, now he  has to go to url, select the url then click on copy then it will copy, but if we directly have a copy button that could be used to copy url, it's good.

Answer (score 2):

Function to copy url. (window.location.href)

```
  const copyMe = () => {
    const url = window.location.href;
    console.log(url);
  };
```

Calling the Function

```
<button onClick={copyMe}> Share </button>
```

For More functionality you can show toast as well when the text is copied.

Comment: This doesn't copy anything

Comment: this should copy the url, can you share your code.

Comment: To copy a text you have to run `navigator.clipboard.writeText`

Comment: yes if you want to copy text, but can you copy url from this method ?